# Can htaccess override CodeIgniter's routes.php

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, routes, url-routing, url-masking

I'm wondering if it's possible to override routes.php rules with htaccess in Codeigniter 3.

For example, in order to point dynamic subdomains to the same controllers and pass the subdomain as a parameter, routes.php falls short for doing this, while in htaccess is really simple to do.

Another example is to mask query strings with URL segments. Routes.php doesn't allow to use query strings, but htaccess is, again, perfect for this.

So, as a general question, is it possible to use htaccess for all routing in CodeIgniter instead of using routes.php?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use htaccess for static routing in codeigniter. But for dynamic routing application base like http://localhost/myproject/user/1 
you have to use routes.php.

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter routes config is used to route module/controller/method/variable patterns.

I think, domain/subdomains go out from this config, however you could use dinamic base_url, based on $_SERVER variables, and then get the string (subdomain) from the specific controller.

From my config, on CI 2.x

```
$config['base_url'] = isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTPS']) == 'on' ? 'https' : 'http';
$config['base_url'] .= '://'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$config['base_url'] .= isset($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']) && $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] != '80' && $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] != '443' ? ( ':'.$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] ) : '';
$config['base_url'] .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), '', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
```

then do something like this...

```
$server = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$domain = preg_replace('#^www\.(.+\.)#i', '$1', $server);
$domain = $this->extract_domain($domain);
$subdomain = $this->extract_subdomains($server);

function extract_domain($domain)
{
    if(preg_match("/(?P<domain>[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]{1,63}\.[a-z\.]{2,6})$/i", $domain, $matches))
    {
        return $matches['domain'];
    } else {
        return $domain;
    }
}

function extract_subdomains($domain)
{
    $subdomains = $domain;
    $domain = $this->extract_domain($subdomains);

    $subdomains = rtrim(strstr($subdomains, $domain, true), '.');

    return $subdomains;
}
```